# CRM 2011 Plugin to Populate Case Closed Date

Tags: plugins, crm

I'm creating a simple plugin in CRM 2011 to autopopulate Case closed date when a Case is resolved. For this I register my plugin in "SetState" and "SetStateDynamicEntity" of Incident entity. I created a new date field "new_closeddate" to contain the value.

For some reason my plugin never fires even though I registered it several times and did IISReset. Could anyone please guide me in the right direction? Thank you much for your help.

Here is my code below.

Thanks,

-elisabeth

```
public override void OnExecute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IPluginExecutionContext context)
    {
        var trace = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

        // The InputParameters collection contains all the data passed in the message request.
        var targetReference = context.GetParameterCollection<EntityReference>(context.InputParameters, "EntityMoniker");

        if (targetReference == null)
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(OperationStatus.Failed, "Target Entity cannot be null");

        var state = (OptionSetValue)context.InputParameters["State"];

        /* Only proceed if Incident is being set to Resolved */
        if (state == null || state.Value != 1)
            return;      

        var postImage = context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];

        if (postImage == null)
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(OperationStatus.Failed, "Post Image is required");

        var serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        var service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        Entity CaseIncident = new Entity("incident");
        CaseIncident.Attributes = new AttributeCollection();
        CaseIncident.Attributes.Add("new_closeddate", DateTime.Now);

    }

    protected override bool CanExecute(IPluginExecutionContext context)
    {
        return context.PreConditionCheck(
            0,
            new List<int> { MessageProcessingStage.AfterMainOperationInsideTransaction },
            new List<string> { MessageName.Update },
            new List<string> { Schema.Incident.EntityLogicalName });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle Close message instead of SetState/SetStateDynamicEntity.